# Best way to install light switch inside the bathroom which is currently outside

Tags: motion-sensor

I have a light switch installed outside the bathroom which I would like to install inside the bathroom so I can install a motion sensor light switch.

What is the best way to do this? Should I install a 3-way switch or remove it from outside and move it inside?

If possible I would like to have the fan and light turn on from the same sensor switch but the fan and light are on 2 different circuit breakers.

Comment: I haven't seen an "occupancy sensor" (what they are sometimes called) that will switch two separate circuits.  As far as the move or use 3-way question, is there ever a need to control the light from outside?

Comment: Also, are the breakers for the fan-circuit and the light-circuit adjacent to each other?

Comment: Light switch outside the bathroom is common in 1900-1920 stock.  Even more common where the WC is separate from the sink/tub.  I'm talking US stock typically found in ca.1900 cities.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt your fan and light are on two separate breakers.  It's more likely you meant to say they're on two separate switches.

If they really are on two breakers, they must be controlled by two separate switches, or you might re-wire it to feed one of them from the others switch, which would essentially be moving that load to the other breaker, and may negate the need for one of those breakers.

As for how to do the work?

If the wall is clear and unobstructed on the opposite side of the wall where the current switch is, you may be able to remove the switch and protect the wiring, then very carefully destroy the box piece by piece, around the wiring using a drill and sawzall.

Then cut a hole on the opposite side of the wall lining up with where the original box was, and install an 'old work' box there, threading the wiring into it.

Then patch the hole where the switch used to be.

Reinstall the switch or switches that were in the box, and enjoy.